# Replace multiple html attributes with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to make a function that replaces: `addthis:url=` `addthis:title=` and `addthis:description=` in these 3 elements:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" 
addthis:url="http://example.com"
addthis:title="An Example Title"
addthis:description="An Example Description"></a>

<a class="addthis_button_tweet" 
addthis:url="http://example.com"
addthis:title="An Example Title"
addthis:description="An Example Description"></a>

<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"
addthis:url="http://example.com"
addthis:title="An Example Title"
addthis:description="An Example Description"
></a>
```

How do I do it? E.g: with the values `newurl.com`, `newtitle` and `newdescription`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your elements an ID for easy access you can do something like this:

```
<a id="link1" class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"  addthis:url="http://example.com" addthis:title="An Example Title" addthis:description="An Example Description"></a>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById("link1");
el.setAttribute("addthis:url", "new url");
el.setAttribute("addthis:title", "new title here");
el.setAttribute("addthis:description", "new description here");
</script>
```

I'll leave it to you to encapsulate that in a function as required.

Note: if you don't want to or can't give your elements an ID for some reason you could try `document.getElementsByClassName()` on your existing HTML, but IE didn't introduce support until IE9.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to set them all at once? So I don't have to run the code 3 times? I'll set it as correct anyway, but I would be very grateful if you could edit it. hah I had to look up for grateful

Comment: I'd suggest you look into using the jQuery library: makes this sort of thing easy to do with only a couple of lines of (your own) code. Otherwise, if the three `<a>` elements have a containing element such as a `<div>` you could use `document.getElementById("theDivId").getElementsByTagName("a");` to get an array containing the `<a>` elements, then use a `for` loop to set them all.